# I can't start Xampp on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed xampp-linux-x64-5.6.8-0-installer.run and when I type
`/opt/lampp/lampp start`

to start the server I find following error
[image]

I tried following command to check status 
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status`

I find 
`* apache2 is not running`

Now I tried to check the ports
`netstat -tunap | grep LISTEN`

and it seems port 80 is busy .
[image]

What should I do run Xampp?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

First

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and then

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 1):

try this command, i tried it in ubuntu 18.04 and worked.
$ sudo apachetcl stop

If it doesn't work try changing the port that Apache is trying to use. To this you should change every mention of the port 80 in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf for some port that is not in use, maybe 83 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check apache error.log file which shows the exact issue

```
opt/lamp/logs/apache/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

change your apache xampp port to 8080, or stop apache2

```
 sudo systemctl stop apache2
```